# Unable to create table in local dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have locally running DynamoDB and create a table using the shell( localhost:8000/shell/).

Can confirm with the following code:

```javascript
var params = {
  ExclusiveStartTableName: 'STRING_VALUE',
  Limit: 10
};
dynamodb.listTables(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

outputs

```javascript
{"TableNames":["myTable"]}
```

However when I call getItem/PutItem from PHP code it throws the following error

> [Mon Dec 14 11:22:48.266930 2015] [:error] [pid 12] [client
>   10.0.2.2:58042] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException: AWS Error Code:
>   ResourceNotFoundException, Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID:
>   8de599f1-7aa6-4147-b2f8-b3acc74b09da, AWS Error Type: client, AWS
>   Error Message: Cannot do operations on a non-existent table,
>   User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.8.24 Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.35.0
>   PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14\n  thrown in
>   /opt/lib/aws/sdk/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php
>   on line 91

And this is how I create the client

```php
$this->client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'key' => 'YOUR_KEY', 
    'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET', 
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    //'version' => '2012-08-10',
    'endpoint'=> 'http://localhost:8000',
    //'debug'   => true
));
```

If the endpoint were wrong, client creation itself would have thrown error but in this case tables are not getting created as per PHP

```php
echo "List of tables";
$iterator = $this->client->()->getIterator('ListTables');
foreach ($iterator as $tableName) {
    echo $tableName . "\n";
}
```

prints nothing.

Comment: What parameters odes the JavaScript client have (region, and others), is from a browser, and how are you starting up DynamoDBLocal (what command line arguments)?

Comment: The JS api did not have any region info but while starting the dynamoDB service I did not mention -sharedDb which according to the documentation is hardcoded to us-west-2. I tried mentioning -sharedDb during launch also but did not work despite JS api confirming that it exists

Comment: Just realized I had a typo in the endpoint URL. It seems to be working now. I was expecting it will show some error for invalid URL instead of just saying table does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

I have just answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40806393/1061798

Check how you are starting dynamoDB. You need to add a -sharedDb flag as described in my answer in the link above